# CEWP to show images (HTML) works until I use grouping. Then I see the DIV tag

Tags: image, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, grouping, content-editor

I'm fairly new to Share Point so forgive me if this is to easy for you guys, but I could not seem to find the answer anywhere and I am rather stumped.

I am currently trying to make a website to track if particular tasks go over their due date. I have a calculated column that leaves a DIV tag to the image of a red/yellow/green circle which is displayed by the javascript for a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) made by Christophe on his site here:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/

I was able to put his code into the CEWP and everything looks great when it is in a standard list.

But I want a web part version of this on the homepage for easy view. When I make the web part (of a view grouping by the image tag) and place on the main site all I see is the DIV tag! I made sure to put an identical CEWP on the homepage as well but i get as grouping:

+[columnName] : DIV>img title=blahblahblah>/DIV> (2)

Needles to say when I expand this it stays the same for all entries below

Any Ideas?

Thanks for your time :D

Answer (score 1):

Nobody has responded, but I found the answer so hopefully this will save someone the hours of grief I had. This will seem ridiculous but just go with it.

In the calculated column instead of returning the type as text, return it as a currency. Sounds ridiculous BUT IT WORKS!!